# Initializing git flow

Tags: git-flow

I already have an existing repository with a couple of branches. I try to initialize git flow here, using the source tree. But when I execute "git flow" command and it tries to initialize the git flow, I get the following error:

```
E:\IdeaProject\IdeLab1>git flow init
Fatal: Working tree contains unstaged changes. Aborting.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `git status` shows you changes, you should add and commit first, before `git flow init`.

Or, if you don't care about those pending changes: `git reset --hard` (then `git flow init`)

If that persists, [`nvie/gitflow` issue 6401](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/6401) mentioned the interference with other tools like [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt).